# What is the weak entity in this ER diagram

Tags: entity, erd, weak

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wdI0.png

**Please refer to the link above. Is 'billing_info' a weak entity as it depends completely on 'orders'?
And if so, is 'bill_id' discriminator?**

Comment: the relationship in the link is a part of e-commerce website's E-R diagram

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity

Comment: Do you mean billing_info ?@user2828552

Comment: Since billing has no meaning independent of the Order(as for billing, an order must be placed), it should be a weak entity. Please correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: yes 'billing' is actually the 'billing_info'

Comment: is 'billing_info'  a weak entity?

Answer (score 0):

According to your diagram billing_info already have a primary key to identify its all records so its not a weak entity set.Additionally billing_info depends on orders only if all billing_info records  are related with orders(total participation).